# Vim: Exit (:wq) with trailing exclamation mark ! What's the purpose?

Tags: command-line, vim

If one leaves an edited file with `:q!`, then it discards the updates.
If one leaves with with `:wq`, then it writes the updates and quits Vim.

But what's the purpose of **`:wq!`** (with a trailing exclamation mark)?

I have found no good explanation about that.

Comment: ! means don't nag me with warnings; just do it.  (it doesn't make that much sense in that example; as if the reason you got warnings was you don't have permissions to write the file, the ! has no effect anyway)

Comment: [vi.se] exists too!

Comment: Have you tried :help!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

"!" means *don't nag me with warnings*; just do it.

If you try and `vim /etc/hosts`, and make changes and try and save with `:wq!` - the "!" is moot.  That is a real error that can't be forced thus use of "!" won't work.

A useful example..

```
touch ~/example
chmod -w ~/example
vim ~/example
```

If you open a file where you have READ access only but have taken away your WRITE access before hand,  that warning can be overridden by the "!" (unlike permissions error in `/etc/`), thus a ":wq!" in this case is handy (*quicker than jumping to shell to fix*).

Comment: Ah, ... I think I've got it. It forces the write-action, instead of displaying a warning. Saying that you are lacking the write-permission. You're example is great. Thanks a big bunch.

Comment: Another common case is invoking vim as `view` or `vim -R`, which opens the file in read-only mode even if you have permissions. That's useful to avoid accidentally saving, but if you change your mind later and want to save a change, `:w!` is easier than quitting and re-opening.

Comment: @IMSoP oh. So "read-only" isn't really "read-only"?

Comment: @EricDuminil Yeah... it's short-hand for "read _only if I don't change my mind_" :-)

Comment: When I was learning vi, I was told that "!" used in this way is pronounced "dammit".

Answer (score 10):

`:wq!` means "write this buffer then close it, no questions asked." If you have any other buffers open, they stay open and vim doesn't exit.

Comment: @filbranden Thank you for rewriting my answer so it's valid; though you certainly could have written it as your own answer instead of editing mine. I forgot to delete mine.

Comment: It's a great answer, in fact it was my favorite here. Don't worry if you got it wrong at first... Editing until it looks good is totally fair. (Fun fact: one of my highest voted answers in one of the SE sites is one I got wrong at first and had to fix!)

Answer (score -1):

`:x!` does the same thing and I have no idea where `:wq!` came from in modern documentation since it was obsolete 4 decades ago.

The problem with `wq!` is does that mean write then force quit or force write and then quit? With `x!` it is clear.

Comment: I've assumed it means “force write-and-quit”. I.e. it parses as `:(wq)!`. No? — The advantage of `wq` might be memorising only two letters, rather than separate `w`, `q` and `x` commands.

Comment: The advantage to vim is that it's very easy to chain together very simple commands into complex actions, and a lot of old timers (and people they've taught/influenced) still prefer wq. I however am lazy enough to just use x, but I recognize that I'm in the minority of vim users I know.

Comment: `:wq` and `:x` have another slight difference in behavior, as `:wq` will write the file unconditionally (even if it was not modified), while `:x` will only write it if it has been modified inside Vim. It's a small distinction, but in some cases it might matter...